# php foreach visible on page

Tags: php, xml, xampp

In my PHP code I have this:

```
$filename = 'data.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$variable = "";
foreach ($data->file_info as $record)
{
    $id1 = $record['id1'];
    $id2 = $record['id2'];
}
```

And it works perfectly fine on the web server, but when trying to view it locally (using xampp) I get the following output at the top of my pgae:

```
file_info as $record)
{
    $id1 = $record['id1'];
    $id2 = $record['id2'];
}
```

(followed by another 100 or so lines of PHP)

Not sure if it would make a difference, the web server it works on is running linux, and I am trying to view it on windows using xampp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `short_open_tag` is set to on in `php.ini` / change `<?` to `<?php`. If that doesn't do it, check apache's logs to see what is going on. Also check if php is defined as the handler for .php files in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Aah you've got me. I always use <?php aside from this one time. Every other part of the script uses <?php, to think this has stumped me for so long.